# AngularJS does my model data become invalid if ng-if evaluates to false?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ng-if

Let's say that I have something like

```
<div ng-if="{{someCondition}}">
    <input type="text" ng-model="myVariable"/>
</div>
```

If `someCondition` is false and that DIV gets removed from the DOM, what, if anything happens to `$scope.myVariable`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nothing happens [(see reference)](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf).

`ng-if` just determines if the html element is created in the DOM. When it exist the `<input>` value is bidirectionally binded to `$scope.myVariable`.

Comment: So it's not exactly two way data binding? Insomuch as destroying the DOM element does not destroy the bound `ng-model`.

Comment: Well... in fact each time `ng-if` evaluates to false the element scope is destroyed and then re-created again when it evaluates to true. Thanks to prototypal inheritance you won't really notice this difference when you are inside a controller, so basically your `$scope.myVariable` is updated when the `<input>` element exists but isn't destroyed when it is removed, because only the element scope is destroyed

Comment: Not sure my explanation is really clear... In the link to reference is clearly explainend when it says 'Note that when an element is removed using `ngIf`...'

Answer (score 2):

First thing `ng-if` expression shouldn't have `{{}}` interpolation directive with it.

```
<div ng-if="someCondition">
    <input type="text" ng-model="myVariable"/>
</div>
```

In above case, when `someCondition` scope value is `not defined` OR `!=null` at that time only that `div`/`element` get removed from the DOM tree,

> As you are thinking what will happen with `myVariable` variable which
>   is present inside it?

So that will remain as is, because scope value has been bounded to controller instance. So till controller instance is there till that time that scope value will exist.